# not able to run python unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-unittest

I am getting errors while execution of unit test cases

- OS: Mac
- IDE: Pycharm
- Python version: 3.7.2

My project structure is:

```
myapp
  - myapp
    - app.py
    - __init__.py
  - test
    - test_app.py
    - __init__.py
```

My test file is pretty simple:

```
import unittest
from myapp import app


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.client = app.app.test_client()
        response = self.client.get('/', content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have provided the commands I tried from project root and their output:

1. *python test/test_app.py*: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
2. *python -m unittest test/test_app.py Test.test*: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Test'

Comment: try: from myapp.myapp import app

Comment: also: from myapp.test.test_app import Test

Comment: @ncica This didn't work. Getting same errors

Comment: Could you please take a project tree screenshot? Do you try to run tests in the terminal? Why don't you use PyCharm run configurations? Meanwhile `python -m unittest test.test_app` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear for me if you are trying to setup a configuration inside PyCharm or are you trying to launch unit test using prompt.

So, if you want use configuration inside Pycharm you should filled up the the *Target* row with the following path:

```
myapp.test.test_app
```

Please note that it's necessary to use "." and not "/" and you don't add the extension of the file (.py). 
Furthermore don't forget to check the correct interpreter.

If you want instead use the command prompt, you should set up all environment variables and then use the following command:

```
python <your>\<manage>\<path>\manage.py test myapp.test.test_app
```

I suggest to use the first option (Pycharm configuration) because all environment variables are already set in your project.